# Fingerprint sensor disabled by Windows 10 update 1803

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint, windows-10-v1803

I recently installed update 1803 on my HP Windows 10 laptop. The fingerprint sensor stopped working. I don't know if was turned off or disabled or what.

Is there a way I can fix it? I found a thread about it [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello/fingerprint-and-pin-not-working-in-winows-10-pro/2998597c-33c8-420d-b4df-a21b7007228d), but I'm not sure what they they are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I had to edit the registry with regedit, open the folder

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System
```

and add a new DWord key with name

```
AllowDomainPINLogon
```

and value

```
00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my HP notebook that the Biometric Device has been gone from Device Manager.

First I updated the driver with [Driver Booster](https://www.iobit.com/en/driver-booster.php) and then uninstall that from Device Manager.

Now it works fine.